# Windows Phone Emulator is unable to create a differencing disk

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am getting this error while deploying or debugging windows phone 8.1 app.

> Windows Phone Emulator is unable to create a differencing disk: A
>   virtual disk support provider for the specified file was not found.

[image: screenshot of error]

Answer (score 2):

That error means that *.vhd files must not be encrypted and must not be compressed.
Then you have to uncompress the folder that containt *.vhd files and try again.

Command line to launch emulator:
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0\xde.exe" /vhd "C:\
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Emulation\Images\flash.vhd
" /name WP8-SDK

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MS forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f12c1b24-a753-4493-84a7-f58213e42195/the-wp-emulator-wasnt-able-to-create-a-differencing-disk-0xc03a001a?forum=wptools) you might be able to get the emulator to run with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.0\xde.exe" /vhd "C:\WP8\Images\Flash.vhd" /name WP8-SDK
```

That command might also give you more output as to why the emulator won't start.

Comment: What is WP8-SDK
I have run this command and got following error
Windows Phone Emulator is unable to set the VHD on the virtual machine:...

Comment: Couldn't change Virtual hard drive of the virtual machine: 'Default Windows Phone Emulator' failed to add device 'Virtual Hard Disk'. (Virtual machine ID 90AAF75A-748F-4F60-9CF0-3207E637F997)

Failed to open attachment 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Emulation\Images\Flash.vhd'. Error: 'Element not found.'.

'Default Windows Phone Emulator': Cannot get information for attachment 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Emulation\Images\Flash.vhd'. (Virtual machine ID 90AAF75A-748F-4F60-9CF0-3207E637F997)

...

Comment: Failed to open attachment 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Emulation\Images\Flash.vhd'. Error: 'Element not found.'.

Comment: @user3782078 Do you have a .vhd file there? You should point the `xde.exe` to where you have your .vhd file.

Comment: Yes i have vhd file there

Comment: I have tried this command
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\8.1\xde.exe" /vhd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Emulation\Images\Flash.vhd"

Comment: Do you have sufficient rights? Can you try to run it with elevated permissions? If it's not that I'm afraid I don't know what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by running up the Hyper V Manager and starting the VM manually.

I restarted the machine first, launched Hyper V Manager, then clicked Start on the VM (WVGA 4 inch 512MB). It started ok. I then closed it, and it then worked from VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible if you've enabled **file compression** on your disk..

Go to properties of the folder > General > Advanced 
and uncheck the "Compress contents to save disk space" checkbox.

> C:\ Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\

I hope it will help you.

[image]

Thanks,

Suraj

http://codeblock.in